# What is the point of force sensitive only talents being marked in a talent tree for force sensitives

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

In Star Wars: Edge of the Empire there is a single force talent tree called "Force Sensitive Exile". In the blurb about this tree it says "In Edge of the Empire, the primary way one becomes a Force-sensitive character is by choosing the Force Sensitive Exile specialisation".

This obviously implies that if you have chosen this specialisation you are by definition force sensitive. Given you cannot buy any of the talents from this spec without having bought the spec first why does it label some (but not all) of the talents as "Force sensitive only"? It is the only place in the book that this restriction is referenced and it seems totally superfluous.

I can imagine situation from my knowledge of Expanded universe why they might be relevant (eg if you are cut off from the force then you can't use those talents but could use others from the tree) but this is with reference from outside the book.

Have I missed a rule somewhere that makes sense of this tag on the talents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm still looking for the sidebar where I thought I read the answer on this issue, but initial scans of EotE and F&D have not turned up anything.

For now, I will give you a quote from Sam Stewart, Senior RPG Producer at Fantasy Flight Games (and the top guy at FFG for all issues related to the Star Wars Role Playing Games):

> You are correct, none of the specializations in Force and Destiny give you Force Rating 1. So if your career does not make you Force Sensitive (as Force and Destiny's careers do) you must take Exile or Emergent to become Force Sensitive. Note, this does not stop you from taking Healer as a tree, but you will be unable to use any Force talents (including talents that increase your Force Rating; those will be "dormant" until you gain Force Rating 1).

Scroll to the bottom of the entry at https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/108101-ffg-developer-answered-questions/page-5#entry1373510 if you want to read the original article in question.

Comment: Blargh.  I could have sworn I read this in a sidebar on a page in an unexpected place, but now I can't find it.  I will modify the answer to include a quote from Sam Stewart at FFG.

Comment: I assume Sam Stewart is some kind of authoritative person? In fact I have now seen he is a FFG RPG Producer so presumably is an authority on the game. Could you edit the answer to indicate his position (and thus his ability to make authoritative statements).

Comment: Sam is the top guy at FFG for all issues related to SWRPG, which is now reflected in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is probably the closest we can get to a proper answer. Its still not perfect because the answer is in context of F&D rather then EotE but I guess the answer is that getting force sensitive is something special about the trees in EotE which is why the fact that some are force only doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, that and the fact that I believe all the books were planned out well in advance, so that they could integrate with each other as much as possible.  For example, there are still a number of talents in the game that are ranked, but where there is only one rank of that talent available from all of the known careers/specializations.  So, the assumption has to be that there are more ranks of those talents yet to come, in careers/specializations that have not yet been published.  I'm happy to try to help improve the answer in any way I can, if you can help me understand where it needs it.

Comment: At the point I asked the question only EotE was out. The answer to why there are force only talents in a tree that guarantees you being force talented is that the EotE ones are unusual (from what you say) in granting force sensitivity. So it makes sense to have force only talents in a tree, the key thing is that the EotE trees are strange in their granting of force sensitivity. Are the F&D characters just automatically force sensitive with force rating 1 or do they get that from some other source?

Comment: If you start out with an F&D Career, then you get FR1.  But none of the Specializations provide FR by themselves, although some of them do give you the ability to buy that talent further down the tree.  So, if you didn't start in F&D, then you need to go through either Force Sensitive Exile or Force Sensitive Emergency to get the base FR1, afterwards you can go into the F&D specializations.

Comment: Wow, I never knew that. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I think this is just a way to reinforce for players, GM's and supplement authors that these skills are attached to Force use.  It's reasonable to assume the authors are future proofing some of these talents.

It's possible that career specializations released in future expansions could have talent tree options only available to force users.  For instance they could add a Rebel Spy career that both organics and droids could take, but would have a few options on the tree that where force based. Maybe even a few other options that would be droid only.  This would save them from having to create separate Force Spy and Droid spy talent trees.

Remember that the first book for the system is less focused on Force use.  It's only in there since you can't really release a new Star Wars RPG without some mention of the Force.  I'm sure we'll see Force use better defined and expanded with future releases.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might be future proofing but I also thought I might have missed something. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The Force Sensitive Exile Talent Tree is not all force powers. It's a collection of talents that a Force Sensitive Exile would pick up. Some are force related talents, others are merely trained abilities. Further, the actual Powers are separate trees, and may be taken by other force careers as well. (Acknowledging that the *Edge of the Empire* Core Book only has one. See the week 4 update for the *Age of Rebellion Beta*.)

When one gets into the expanded game, as is the case with combining the *Age of Rebellion Beta* with the *Edge of the Empire* Corebook, most of the non-force sensitive talents listed are available in non-force careers's specialties. (AoR also has a second force tree, the Force Sensitive Emergent.)

Further, having them marked in the big list in the corebook allows easier and more consistent home-brew additions. Whether this is intentional or not can be argued, but the practical effect is still that it helps keep homebrew add-ons more consistent by showing which ones actually require a force rating.

Further still, it's a GM cross check for published NPC's. If any such talents show up, the opponent has a force rating of at least 1. This has not been relevant to date in published adventures, but could be later on.

Answer (score 2):

One reason: Droid PCs can buy the specs and the force sensitive only talents, but gain no benefit from those talents.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a moment to check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an idea of how it works.

Comment: Hi Streak. This seems to be very similar to Brad's answer that suggests that anybody can buy the talents but you have to be force sensitive to use them. Are there parts of the rules that you can point me at that talk about droids specifically with the force sensitive talents?

Comment: While it *is* similar to Brad's answer, in that it explains why they're flagged in the F&D trees, it *also* explains why they're flagged in the Emergent and Exile trees as well.  A droid *can* buy into either (or even both) of those trees.  Said droid would be unable to use the flagged talents because they require the user to be force sensitive, and droids *cannot* become force sensitive (as per the rules).  Not every talent in the trees requires the Force to utilize, so not all of the talents in the trees get flagged as such.

Answer (score -1):

I think its because the book has a single "master list" of all the talents in alphabetical order and they attached the "force sensitive only" tag to each of those talents to help them stand apart when they are being viewed in a way that is detached from the talent "tree." Tagging them this way also probably helped with internal consistency as the book was being edited.

Comment: That doesn't really answer why some, but not all have that tag. Obviously it can be used as a tag just for labelling but that doesn't answer what the logic behind why certain talents (or indeed what the need is). Editing/consistency doesn't seem to be a logical reason because you could have things useful for ensuring that without them needing to be in the final version...